# Nomencl and Algorithm2e Incompatibility

Tags: incompatibility, algorithm2e, nomenclature

This code produces no errors and displays the nomenclature correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$c$}{a constant}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

If I add the algorithm package:

```
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
```

I get:

```
Undefined control sequence. [\begin{thenomenclature}]
```

and no nomenclature.

Is there a conflict between the packages? How can I debug this?

### Edit

Using Tex Live 2012

```
Package: nomencl 2005/09/22 v4.2
Package: algorithm2e 2008/00/00 v3.10
```

### Solved

Upgrading algorithm2e to version 5.00 (2013/01/06) fixes the problems.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: i'm unable to reproduce the error you report.  i'm using tex live 2012 except for a newer version of `algorithm2e`, `Release 5.0 -- january 06 2013`.  this may make a difference.

Comment: I see I'm using an old algorithm2e package, v 3.10 from 2008.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was fixed by updating packages.